# how i must using if for this angularjs and php code

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, arrays

I want to make one if for doing if array result was success alart somethings in 
this code: `if( data.status == 'success'){` is not working!!
it was with one = but result of one = is alwase 200 , I want to check status array if was success alert ... 
I testthis code: data.data.statusin other place with just one array and this code work but when i use data.data.status in bottom codes its not working !!
angularjs function code :

```
$scope.book = function(){

        if( $scope.cabs[$scope.active_cab].intialkm >= $scope.trip_distance) {
            $scope.trip_rate = $scope.cabs[$scope.active_cab].intailrate ;
        }else{
            var init_rate =  $scope.cabs[$scope.active_cab].intailrate ;

          var std_rate  =  ( $scope.trip_distance - $scope.cabs[$scope.active_cab].intialkm ) * $scope.cabs[$scope.active_cab].standardrate ;

            $scope.trip_rate = round_num( parseFloat(init_rate) + parseFloat(std_rate) );
        }

        $rootScope.user_data = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('user_data') );         

        var link = 'book_cab';
        var post_data = {  
                        'user_name'    : $rootScope.user_data.User_name,
                        'token'          : $rootScope.user_data.token,
                        'transfertype' : "Point to Point Transfer" ,
                        'book_date'    : $scope.book_date ,
                        'pickup_area'  : $scope.start_box.location,
                        'drop_area'    : $scope.end_box.location,
                        'taxi_type'    : $scope.selected_cab.cartype,
                        'km'                     : $scope.trip_distance,
                        'amount'             : $scope.trip_rate 
                     }

        WebService.show_loading();  

        var promise = WebService.send_data( link,post_data);

        promise.then(function(data){  

            $ionicLoading.hide();
            if( data.status == 'success'){
                alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: '<p class="text-center color-yellow">'+$filter('langTranslate')("SUCCESS",$rootScope.appConvertedLang['SUCCESS'])+'</p>',
                    template: '<p class="text-center color-gery">'+$scope.trip_distance+' KM</p>'+
                                        '<p class="text-center color-gery"> ₹ '+$scope.trip_rate+'</p>'
                });
                animateMyPop();
            }else{
                window.alert(response.data);
                window.alert(response.status);
            }
        });
    }
```

php webservice :

```
public function book_cab(){

    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $request = json_decode($postdata);

    $request->uneaque_id = 'CMC'.strtotime(date('m/d/Y H:i:s'));



    $myDate = new DateTime();
    $myDate->setTimestamp( strtotime( $request->book_date) );

    $time =  $myDate->format("H");

    if( $time >= 22 ||  $time <= 6){
        $request->timetype = 'night';
    }else{
        $request->timetype = 'day';
    }

    $request->book_date   =  $myDate->format("m/d/Y");
    $request->pickup_time =  $myDate->format("h:i a");

    $request->token = $this->extract_token( $request->token );
    var_dump($request );
    $finresult = array( 'status'  => 'success',
                                'message' => 'Successfully registered',
                                'code'    => 'registered' 
                                        );
            print json_encode($finresult);  
    $this->model_web_service->book($request);

}
```

and model_web_service:

```
 function book( $request ){

      $table = 'bookingdetails';

        $insert_data = array(
            'username'    => $request->token,
            'uneaque_id'    => $request->uneaque_id,
            'purpose'       => "Point to Point Transfer",
            'pickup_date' => $request->book_date,
            'pickup_time' => $request->pickup_time,

            'drop_area'     => $request->drop_area,
            'pickup_area' => $request->pickup_area,

            'taxi_type'   => $request->taxi_type,
            'status'            => "Booking",
            // 'item_status' => "Pending",

            'timetype'      => $request->timetype,
            'amount'          => $request->amount,
            'km'                    => $request->km
        );

            $this->insert_table($insert_data, $table);                      
 }
```

i want to change if for read php status array (success) 
plz help me for fixing this code

Comment: The result of `data.status` will always be a HTTP code, as stated in [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). The `200` status code means [success](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

Comment: i know this i want to know i must change this code to what for change result to success

Comment: i change data.status to dada.data.status , this not working too , but data.data.status is working if array was just one and before array wasnt any other code

Comment: ... I'm sorry, I just can't understand what you want to achieve here... Why don't you want to check `data.status === 200`?

Comment: i want check that status array from php code in angularjs code , and show some result after checking if status === "success"

Comment: php array is this : $finresult = array( 'status'  => 'success',
                                'message' => 'Successfully registered',
                                'code'    => 'registered' 
                                        );
            print json_encode($finresult);
but when i use data.data.status i cant  get success from this array in my angularjs code

Comment: Can you open up the Chrome DevTools, and monitor the network while doing your AJAX request (just click on the `network` tab)? Find your request, and look at the response you get, so that we'll know if your data is there.